# Crash on SE Android app when applying blockquote to a text selection

Tags: bug, android-app

Whenever I select the text on the  image below and try to

> quote it

[image]

I get a crash:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Sometimes happens to me on iOS, but I doubt any fix will be made since development has halted

Comment: Why it's halted?

Comment: @AndrewLi I doubt SE apps development isn't active. Where did you find that info ?

Comment: @PedroLobito SE dev employees have said they won't be doing any work (some might release fatal bug fixes, if any).

Comment: What's he alternative to this app? Is it deprecated?

Comment: Could you link to the post you're trying to add the quote on? I tried to reproduce it here but couldn't. Also, the mobile devs have been pulled to Team DAG; they don't work for the mobile app for now.

Comment: I wish we could get an official post on the state of the app, it's rather confusing right now. All I see is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307189/300549) plus some comments here and there.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just add a > ? No crashes.

Comment: Can you cause this crash again, click on "submit feedback", then "system info" (or "preview"), and tell us what the "exception class name" is?